# 3 Stacked views with autolayout resizing and animating

Tags: uiview, resize, autolayout

I've been working with autolayout in IB but can't seem to get the results i want, an image should better illustrate this issue.

[image: The view setup]

When the top view (hidden behind the navigation bar) animates down the green view needs to scale its size to accommodate for the top view (basically shrink). The top view can also animate back upwards so the green view needs to resize and get bigger again.

The green view also has some content, a UIImage and a UIlabel, the UIImage needs to scale to match the green view container, and the label simply needs to move.

In terms of code after animating the object i do update the layout, see below:

```
// move record view
```

- (void)moveViews:(UIView *)iAdView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration curve:(int)curve playBackwards:(BOOL)playBackwards{

```
// setup the animation with a block
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration

 // animtations for first loop (slide off screen)
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
                     [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
                     [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];

                     // the transform matrix
                     CGAffineTransform moveObject;

                     if (!playBackwards) {
                         // the transform down
                         moveObject = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, adView.frame.size.height*2);
                     }
                     else{
                         // the transform up
                         moveObject = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -adView.frame.size.height*2);

                     }

                     // move the views
                     [iAdView setTransform:moveObject];

                     // reset for auto layout
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     if (!playBackwards) {
                         NSLog(@"Anim down is complete");
                     }
                     else{
                         NSLog(@"Anim up is complete");
                     }
                 }];
// commit changes
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

However i simply can't seem to get this behaviour to work, the middle view will simply not scale, it either doesn't move or all the views move around even if they are pinned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok no one has jumped on this, after much reading, and testing out stuff in the IDE i've finally managed to get the autolayout to function as required. General rule of thumb is understanding that each view needs to managed based on what its subviews and parent views are doing as well.

I found this tutorial specifically the bit about intrinsic sizes and content hugging / content resistance very informative and enlightening

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_Auto_Layout_in_iOS_6